# npm init not creating package.json on my mac

Tags: json, node.js, npm

When I try to create a `package.json` file using `npm init` I keep getting the following:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/init
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/init
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/daemon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/daemon
init@0.1.2 node_modules/init
└── daemon@1.1.0
```

What is wrong? I have looked everywhere and I cannot find an answer.
Here is what I get when I run the following command:

```
Amens-Mac-mini:~ amenmojara$ npm init =ddd
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/%3Dddd
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/init
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/init
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/%3Dddd
npm ERR! 404 '%3Dddd' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "init"   "=ddd"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/amenmojara
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/amenmojara/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.

1. Go to terminal.
2. Change directory location where you want to create a file.

   `cd your_destination_folder`
3. Type `npm init` and press enter.
4. It ask for `name, version, description, entry point, test command, git repository, keywords, author, license`. Pass those values.
5. Then it prompt, `Is this ok? (yes)`. Enter `yes`.

Hurray, your `package.json` file is created.

[image: terminal snapshot]

Comment: I have tried that and I get the out put you saw when I posted this question.

Comment: I guess, you can try `sudo npm init`. It will ask for admin password. I am not sure, whether it helps or not, but have a try atleast.

Comment: Yeah I have to add sudo nom init and it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `npm install init` instead of `npm init`. Just check if your `npm <something>` is not aliased to `npm install <something>`

Comment: if you are using bash shell, the aliases are mostly defined in one of the bash config files - 

/etc/profile
~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile
~/.bash_logout
~/.bashrc

Comment: try this. check where is npm located by doing `which npm`. copy that location and run it giving full path. On my mac - `/usr/local/bin/npm init`

Comment: on my mac it is /usr/local/bin/npm I just ran nom init -ddd and edited my question does that output tell you anything?

Comment: yes it does... try running `npm install init =ddd`, you should see the same output